# Multiple primary & foreign keys Access

Tags: ms-access, foreign-keys, primary-key

I am using Access 2007.

Tables:
- Budget Lines (project_id (PK), donor_code (PK), ...)
- Contracts (project_id (FK), donor_code (FK), ...)

PK = Primary Key
FK = Foreign Key

Let's say that I have entered the field project_id in the table Contracts, and I now want to enter the field donor_code: what do I need to do to make sure that I can only choose among the donor_codes that are combined with the project_id that I entered and not all the existing budget codes ?

Comment: Your question mentions Primary and Foreign Keys, so have you actually established a [Relationship](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/guide-to-table-relationships-HA010120534.aspx) between the two tables? Have you investigated [referential integrity](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/guide-to-table-relationships-HA010120534.aspx#_Toc269752116) and how you can [enforce](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/guide-to-table-relationships-HA010120534.aspx#_Toc269752121) it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, having 2 fields as primary key has always looked awkward to me.

My suggestion would be to add an autonumber field in your budget_lines table and declare it as the primary key. Then, you can index the 2 other fields to ensure that there are no duplicates.

As far as I understand, you have a Project table and a Donor table which are both linked to the budget lines table. And then you want to link these buddget lines to contracts.

If you input the data directly in the table, I can't seem to find a solution. Still if you input them through a form, with a little of VBA some workarounds can be found.

One way would be to use the after_update event of your combo boxes for ProjectID and Donor_Code to modify the row source of the query of the other combo box of the pair.

The code would look something like that :

> Private Sub ProjectID_AfterUpdate()
>
> > If Me!ProjectID.Value Is Null Then
> >
> > > ```
> > >    Me.DonorCode.RowSource = "SELECT BudgetLines.Donor_Code, BudgetLines.Whatever >FROM BudgetLines;"  
> > > Else  
> > >     Me.DonorCode.RowSource = "SELECT BudgetLines.Donor_Code, BudgetLines.Whatever  FROM BudgetLines WHERE BudgetLines.ProjectID= " & [Me]![ProjectID] & ";"  
> > > End If
> > > ```
> > >
> > > End Sub